# BLE device does not respond to command

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have some specific `BLE` device, that imitate socket connection by two characteristics - write and read. So if you write any command for the “write” characteristic, the “read” characteristic will give you an answer by notification.

It works corret when I use bluetooth terminal `nRF Connect`. But when I try to repeat it using `Android` API the device does not respond to command.

I create `BluetoothGattCallback` object and start to connect with my device:

```
BluetoothGattCallback callback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            gatt.discoverServices();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        BluetoothGattService cccdService = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString("00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic cccdCharacteristic = cccdService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        BluetoothGattService deviceService = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString("569a1101-b87f-490c-92cb-11ba5ea5167c"));
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic writeCharacteristic = deviceService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("569a2001-b87f-490c-92cb-11ba5ea5167c"));
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic readCharacteristic = deviceService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("569a2000-b87f-490c-92cb-11ba5ea5167c"));
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic c2002 = deviceService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("569a2002-b87f-490c-92cb-11ba5ea5167c"));

        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(cccdCharacteristic, true);
        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(readCharacteristic, true);
        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(c2002, true);
        gatt.requestConnectionPriority(BluetoothGatt.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH);

        // makeHeader is method that create byte request
        writeCharacteristic.setValue(makeHeader((byte) 1, (byte) 1, MemoConstDdin.DATA, (short) 1000));
        gatt.writeCharacteristic(writeCharacteristic);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
        displayResponse(characteristic);
    }
};
gatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, callback);
```

Connection successful. Services found. Notifications enabled. Write characteristic successful. But. Method `onCharacteristicChanged` is never called for "read" characteristic.

What's wrong with this code or with me ?
Any idea.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also enable the indication or notification value.

Discover the corresponding descriptor for your characteristic. Then

```
adescriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
gatt.writeDescriptor(adescriptor);
```

Comment: I found `descriptor` 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb in all characteristics. There are no other `descriptors`. Then I set value `BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE` for all of them. But I haven't a result.

Comment: try with `BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE`but only on those characteristics you are waiting for a response.

Comment: It's weird, but it works for `Android 6` test phone, but doesn't work for `Android 9` phone..

Comment: make sure you have these permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`
` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: All permissions are ok. I think it was my bad. I wrote all the commands linearly, including `gatt.writeCharacteristic`. When I put the write function to the button, everything began to work as it should. Thanks for the help, I couldn't have done it without that.